# Drupal 8 - template_preprocess_node not working

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-8, preprocessor

I have created an article listing view with a view mode "Teaser Full Width". The page looks fine and articles listed. When I tried to edit something using `template_preprocess_node(&$variables)`, the hook is not working in Teaser Full Width. But the same work in the individual node when I click any article.

```
<?php
function templatename_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
   kint($variables);die('test');
}
?>
```

I have already gone through different questions in StackOverflow.

1. Devel module enabled.
2. Tried with condition `if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'teaser_full_width'){ ... }`
3. Tried `print_r` instead of `kint`.
4. Tried by changing `max_allowed_packet`.
5. Verified `templatename` is enabled and set as default.
6. Cache Cleared.

**(Article Listing Page)** Template file:- `node--article--teaser-full-width.html.twig`

`template_preprocess_html` is working fine on this page.

`template_preprocess_node` not working on this page.

**(Article Single Page)** Template file:- `node--article--full.html.twig`

Both hooks are working fine.

Does anyone know what the issue is? My drupal version is 8.6.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per drupal's documentation template_preprocess_node() is the hook for node templates. Since the views listing page is containing the nodes but is not a node page so template_preprocess_node() is not working there. However, It is still an html page so template_preprocess_html() works there.

In simple terms, your "article listing view" is a page not node so template_preprocess_node() doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I think if there is a node we can use the node preprocess. Because each items (teaser) in the article listing page is node. How to preprocess those listed item???

Comment: The nodes are listed through the view. So you can preprocess them through template_preprocess_views_view().

Comment: That means we can't use `template_preprocess_node` in teaser listing page using view. It can only be used in node pages and we need to use `template_preprocess_views_view` to alter the contents in teaser listing page. Right?

Comment: Yes. And you can enable the theme debugging mode. This way by doing inspect element. You could see which hook to use for which element. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates